# How to pick a key from a nested Object?

Tags: typescript

From `interface` Person I am trying to pick a key let's say `address`.

```
 interface Person {
    (
        name: string,
        age: number,
        lang: string,
        address: {
            postalCode: number;
            city: string;
            street: string;
        }
    ): void;
}
```

From normal `interface` I would do this

```
type PersonAddress = Pick<Person, "address">
```

But trying to pick from `Person` interface which is a void, using the syntax above throws an error

```
Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'.ts(2344)
```

How to pick from `Person` interface or is it possible in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following fragment achieves it...

```js
 interface Person {
    (
        name: string,
        age: number,
        lang: string,
        address: {
            postalCode: number;
            city: string;
            street: string;
        }
    ): void;
}

type Address = Parameters<Person>[3]
```

The definition you are working with is not an `interface` with keys, it is a function call. The items listed are positional arguments and they have names only to support tooling and documentation.

If it were an interface with keys, the problem would be solved as you originally attempted...

```js
 interface Person {
        name: string,
        age: number,
        lang: string,
        address: {
            postalCode: number;
            city: string;
            street: string;
        }
}

type Address = Person["address"]
```

Comment: can you please explain, what is 3 in square brackets?

Comment: As this is an interface for a call signature with positional arguments (not an interface for an object with named keys) the only thing you can do is investigate its parameters, and they don't 'ACTUALLY' have names, they only have positions in the argument list. Hence 3 gets you the fourth positional argument in the call signature which happens to be the address.